# iOS Storyboards: Can you set button width based on screen size?

Tags: ios, storyboard

Is there a way to set button width/height based on the iPhone screen size? For practice I'm making a "calculator-like" grid (there are more buttons here than I want, but I think this shows my question).

[image: A basic layout I'm trying to make]

I understand this layout is for "all sizes" so the layout WILL get cut off. However, the 4-inch iPhone gets cut off at the BEH column, whereas the 5.5-inch iPhone gets cut off at the CFI column.

[image: Here is the preview]

I've tried to put a superview underneath the buttons to no avail. I also tried auto constraints which made it a mess, and I've tried manually adding all the constraints but it still cuts off my buttons.

**Edit**: Made changes from duran's comments. I tried putting them in separate Views and setting constraints on those, but I still have the following problem. If I set the constraints, they overlap each other.

Here the constraint between middle RED view and the RIGHT green view's "width" constraint is being overwritten by the RIGHT view's "trailing width" constraint.

[image: They are overlapping in both of these]

Next the green is being pushed off from the red "width" constraint between the two views
[image: Green is being pushed off on the right]

I guess here is an updated question: If I want to add the 9 buttons across (they don't fit), is there a way to have them fit through constraints so it looks the same on all screens, or do I have to make the buttons small enough to fit on the smallest screen and have extra white space on all the other screens?

Comment: put each grid into a separate UIView, then put place on your superview, and than set Constraints.

Comment: @Duaan updated the question. I can make the view work if the buttons are tiny but there will be lots of white space on the large devices (iPhone 6/iPads)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. When I put the buttons in a superview, I wasn't using constraints to keep them the same width and bound to the edges of the superview (so they were not resizing when the superview wanted to resize). Here is the updated test I did with two boxes.

[image: Setting constraints on the buttons, too]

I have horizontal spacing between all the buttons and the two superviews also have equal widths (with a multiplier depending on the size I want it).